# How to automate AWS IAM instance profile creation with Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, ansible-2.x

I wanted to automate the creation of IAM instance profile with Ansible. I have looked at the module available in Ansible, but couldn't find any module that will do the job. I have managed to create an IAM role and attached a trust policy to it with the module

```
    iam_role:
      name: updatedns
      assum_role_policy_document: "{{ lookup('file', 'update-dns.json') }}
      state: present
```

But as per AWS documentaiton when using AWSCLI we have to attach the role to an instance profile and that profile is then attached to the principal that we wish to attach it to, in my case EC2. Does anyone know about the Ansible module that will give me this functionality? or Should I use the shell command for awscli?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that there is an open bug with Ansible on this issue:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/30036

Until resolved, I suggest you use the shell command for awscli.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and pointing me in the right direction.